# I've deleted my .sock file - Django, Nginx, Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

When I was trying to pull from Git, I accidentally deleted the sock file. What am I supposed to do now? My websites showing "502 Bad Gateway" and nothing's working. I need help, fast.

Could **you** tell me what to do now?

EDIT:
As this a new project with no data yet, I've just scrapped the server and spun another, done everything again, because nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 3):

Just try to run this command it will create .sock file for you

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
```

this will create **your_project.sock** file and then check the status by typing this command

```
sudo systemctl status gunicorn
```

Comment: Here's my gunicorn status:

Comment: ● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-01-02 14:37:12 UTC; 4s ago
  Process: 21179 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/bookclub/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/bookclu
 Main PID: 21179 (code=exited, status=3)

Comment: Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 gunicorn[21179]:   File "/home/ubuntu/bookclub/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backend
Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 gunicorn[21179]:     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 gunicorn[21179]: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No m
Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 gunicorn[21179]: [2022-01-02 14:37:12 +0000] [21238] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21238)

Comment: Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 gunicorn[21179]: [2022-01-02 14:37:12 +0000] [21179] [WARNING] Worker with pid 21234 was terminat
Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 gunicorn[21179]: [2022-01-02 14:37:12 +0000] [21179] [WARNING] Worker with pid 21238 was terminat
Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 gunicorn[21179]: [2022-01-02 14:37:12 +0000] [21179] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 gunicorn[21179]: [2022-01-02 14:37:12 +0000] [21179] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Comment: Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Jan 02 14:37:12 ip-172-31-44-216 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: I sent it in separate messages 'coz it doesn't fit in one comment

Comment: But looks like gunicorn failed

Comment: You can add this errors in your question by making [edit]

Comment: Hello @Robo it seems there is an error with package named as psycopg2 did you installed that pacakage ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `systemd` enable and start your service. If everything ok with `service` file it will create the `.sock` file again.

```
systemctl start <your service name>
systemctl enable <your service name>
```

Comment: I'm using Gunicorn. Does that mean I need to enable and start Gunicorn in place of `<your service name>`? Sorry if this is a silly question, i'm just new to  all this hosting business.

Comment: have you created a .service file in systemd folder?

Comment: IDK what `systemd` is, never heard of it...

Comment: are you using supervisor or any file gunicorn.service or any .service file?

Comment: Hello @Robo did you created ``gunicorn.service`` file

Comment: @Tasnuva Nope. Not even heard of it.

Comment: Okk, did you followed any tutorial to setup nginx with django?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Yes

Comment: Digitalocean. The problem isn't with the correct hosting, because it was working until a while ago when I tried to pull with git and accidentally delete the sockfile.